# 'varname' is not defined from an API call resonse

Tags: python

I get response from an API call.

```
response = call_api(...)
print(response)
if 'data' not in response:
```

This test cause an exception error:

> 'data' is not defined

In response variable starts with:

```
{'data': [{'type': 'flight-destination', 'origin': 'PAR', 'destination': 'LIS', 'departureDate': '2020-06-21', 'returnDate': '2020-07-03', 'price': {'total': '86.56'},
```

So why do i raise this error :

> data is not defined

Comment: you can use a `try except` statement to check if `response['data']` exists.

Comment: what is the output of `print(response)`. Post the code where it causing the error. code you posted will not cause any error

Comment: It sounds like you probably wrote `if data not in response` rather than `if 'data' not in response`, because the second version would not cause such an error (I know what you posted here, but that error is not reproducible)

Comment: This is a pure, impossible error with the code you have produced :)

Comment: Either as @awarrier99 says or possibly the use of ```response[data]``` later on.

Comment: This is my complete code:
for i in range(from_days,from_days+to_days):
    data = get_prices(origin_city, date_to_reach, False)
    if (data):
        print(data)
def get_prices(origin,date, only_direct):
    try:
        print("Appel API Amadeus avec ville de départ= {}, date de départ= {}".format(origin,date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
        response = call_api(......)
        print(response['data'])
        if data not in response.keys():
            .....
            return []
        else:
            return (response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

Comment: @Theo75: So it's probably the line ```if data not in response.keys():``` -- data does not seem to be defined as a variable, so you probably mean the string "data".

Comment: Strangely print(response['data']) return a result and just after, when i test if the same variable exists ("if not response['data']") raise an exception.... Thanks you a lot.